# Are christians godkind?

Tags: word-study, jesus

2Peter 1:4
By which have been given to us exceedingly great and precious promises, that through these you may be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through lust.

"Partakers of the divine nature"... Does it mean christians are not mere human but godkind?

Comment: _Lo, the man was as **one of us**_ Genesis 3:22 [YLT] This is a question of the righteousness of God - 2 Peter 1:1 _... the righteousness of the God and Saviour of us, Jesus Christ_ (see Sharp's Rule) ... The previous question got side-tracked with 'hypostatic union' and there was  no accepted, satisfactory answer because of it. (Up-voted +1, in the hope of a better outcome than last time.)

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour (below, bottom left) as to the functioning and purpose of the site.

Comment: Despite the question being closed it is worthy of re-opening (in my opinion) but would require an edit to make this happen. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> “That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and **that which is born of the Spirit is spirit**.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭3:6‬ ‭

> “Now the parable is this: **The seed is the word of God**.”
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭8:11‬ ‭

> “since you have been **born again**, not of perishable **seed** but of **imperishable**, through the living and abiding **word of God**;”
> ‭‭1 Peter‬ ‭1:23‬ ‭

> “**who were born**, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but (the will) **of God**.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭1:13‬ ‭

> “No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws him. And I will raise him up on the last day. It is written in the Prophets, ‘And **they will all be taught by God**.’ Everyone who **has heard and learned** from the Father comes to me—”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭6:44-45‬ ‭

To have the divine nature, one must be born again of the spirit, first verse I quoted. *”That which is born of spirit is spirit”*

This is done by **hearing** the good news found in the Scriptures (think O.T.) about a coming deliverer (redeemer, anointed one, savior)

The ‘good news’ is the word of God and IT is the seed.

**ANYONE** who believes the words of the O.T. the Father draws them to Jesus. This is no a bloodlines issue, or something man can will, it is God’s will to draw all men that hear the word and BELIEVE it to Jesus. He, Jesus, is the fulfillment of the O.T.

> “How then will they call on him in whom they have not believed? And how are they to believe in him of whom they have never heard? And how are they to hear without someone preaching?”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭10:14‬ ‭

That’s why it’s so important to expose all men to the ACTUAL gospel/‘good news’, giving men a chance to hear the message the Father intended men to hear (O.T.) and those who hear the word and BELIEVE it voluntarily, without compulsion, of their free will, God will draw them to Jesus. If they then call upon Jesus, then, they will be saved.

> “And it shall come to pass that everyone who calls on the name of the Lord shall be saved”
> ‭‭Joel‬ ‭2:32‬ ‭

The word will have germinated in them, giving them new life, spiritual life from the spirit. *“That which is born of the spirit is spirit.”*

> “Whoever feeds on my flesh and drinks my blood has eternal life, and **I will raise him up on the last day**.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭6:54‬ ‭

And Jesus’ flesh and blood is the life that comes from the Spirit, life found in the word.

> “It is the **Spirit who gives life**; the flesh is no help at all. **The words that I have spoken to you are spirit and life**.
> And he said, “This is why I told you that no one can come to me unless it is granted him by the Father.””
> ‭‭John‬ ‭6:63, 65‬ ‭

If the seed of the word abides in you and you believed it, the Father then drew you to Jesus, and believing in Jesus and you called upon Him, the Lord to be saved -  and if you persevered to keep the word, meaning this seed was not taken away; nor did it sprout but then rotted; nor sprouted, grew, and became overwhelmed with the concerns of this world; but this word is in a believing heart to the very end, this seed/word will guarantee the divine nature remains in that person and as a consequence Jesus will raise them up on the last day.

> “That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit. Do not marvel that I said to you, ‘You must be born again.’ The wind blows where it wishes, and you hear its sound, but you do not know where it comes from or where it goes. So it is with everyone who is born of the Spirit.”
> Jesus answered him, “Are you the teacher of Israel and yet you do not understand these things?”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭3:6-8, 10‬ ‭

Jesus was surprised of Nicodemus, not so much because Nicodemus didn’t know where this was written in the O.T. But that he being a TEACHER of the Scriptures lacked sufficient understanding of these Scriptures.

Are Christians Godkind?

> “We know that **everyone who has been born of God** (by the word of God) does not keep on sinning, but he who was born of God (has the word of God in him) protects him, and the evil one does not touch him.”
> ‭‭1 John‬ ‭5:18‬ ‭

#### Additional meditations

How then shall a man keep his path straight?

> “How can a young man keep his way pure? By guarding it **according to your word**. With my whole heart I seek you; let me not wander **from your commandments**! I have **stored up your word in my heart**, that I might not sin against you. Blessed are you, O Lord; **teach me your statutes**!”
> ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭119:9-12‬ ‭

This is a reoccurring theme in the O.T.

> “Truly, truly, I say to you, **if anyone keeps my word**, he will never see death.””
> ‭‭John‬ ‭8:51‬ ‭

Are these words to be believed like those of the O.T.?

> “For if you believed Moses, you would believe me; for he wrote of me. But if you do not believe his writings, how will you believe my words?””
> ‭‭John‬ ‭5:46-47‬ ‭

And Jesus is greater than Moses, according to Moses himself.

> “Jesus answered him, “If anyone loves me, **he will keep my word**, and my Father will love him, and we will come to him and make our home with him.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭14:23‬ ‭

> “So Jesus said to the Jews who had believed him, “**If you abide in my word, you are truly my disciples**, and you will know the truth, and the truth will set you free.” So if the Son sets you free, you will be free indeed.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭8:31-32, 36‬ ‭

> “If anyone hears my words and does not keep them, I do not judge him; for I did not come to judge the world but to save the world. **The one who rejects me and does not receive my words** has a judge; the word that I have spoken will judge him on the last day. **For I have not spoken on my own authority, but the Father who sent me has himself given me a commandment—what to say and what to speak**.”
> ‭‭John‬ ‭12:47-49‬ ‭

> ““Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, **but the one who does the will of my Father** who is in heaven.
> “**Everyone then who hears these words of mine and does them** will be like **a wise man** who built his house on the rock.”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭7:21, 24‬ ‭